# Python 3 command line Minesweeper game, code error

Tags: python-3.x, minesweeper

Hello guys I'm doing a simple command line version of minesweeper game in python 3 and I'm having some trouble with the code.

The idea is to build a minesweeper game with 2d array to represent a 9x9 grid where the bombs are placed randomly.

This is what i did so far:

```
import random

#Function to create the 9x9 grid
def initialize():
    grid=9
    matrix=[[' ' for i in range(grid)] for i in range(grid)]
    return matrix

#Function to print the grid
def printMat( matrix ):
    print('     0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8')
    for i in range( 9 ):
        print(i,end=' ')
        for j in range( 9 ):
            print('[',matrix[i][j],']',sep = " ",end=' ')
        print('\n')

#Function to place the bombs
def place_bomb(bomb):
    bombs = 10
    while bombs != 0:
        bomb[random.randint(0,8)][random.randint(0,8)] = "*"
        bombs-=1
    return bomb

#Function to calculate the surrounding bombs 
def surrounding(grid, lin, col):
    size = len(grid)
    surrounding = []

    for i in range(-1, 2):
        for j in range(-1, 2):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                continue
            elif -1 < (lin + i) < size and -1 < (col + j) < size:
                surrounding+=lin + i, col + j
    return surrounding



#Function to verify if the player found a bomb and show the updated grid
#Not finished yet
def step(grid, lin, col):
    if grid[lin][col] == '* ':
        print("bomb")
        #return bomb=bomb-1

#Function to verify if the player found all the bombs
#If all the booms were found then return True else return False
#Not finished yet

def status():
   pass



def game():
    game_active=True
    grid=initialize()
    printMat(grid)
    while game_active==True:
        lin = int(input('Choose a line :'))
        col = int(input('Choose a column:'))
        c=place_bomb(grid)
        printMat(c)
        f=surrounding(c,lin,col)
        printMat(f)

game()
```

It return an error from the printMat function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 52, in <module>
    game()
   line 50, in game
    printMat(f)
   line 13, in printMat
    print('[',matrix[i][j],']',sep = " ",end=' ')
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I solve this? 
Any help or tip to build the game would be appreciated

Comment: How can you solve what?  You haven't described a problem you need to have solved.

Comment: Sorry sorry this is my first time using stack overflow.

This is the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 52, in <module>
    game()
   line 50, in game
    printMat(f)
   line 13, in printMat
    print('[',matrix[i][j],']',sep = " ",end=' ')
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what's happening in the `surrounding` function (I simplified it a bit):

```
>>> surrounding=[]
>>> surrounding += 2, 4
>>> surrounding
[2, 4]
```

So, adding a tuple to a list doesn't *append* the tuple to the list, it *extends* the list with the elements of the tuple. This means that this function actually returns a flat list, not a list of lists (aka matrix), so, in the call to `printMat`, `matrix[i]` will be an individual *integer*, which, of course, cannot be indexed with `matrix[i][j]`.

You should *append* the tuple instead of adding it:

```
surrounding.append((lin + i, col + j)) # not surrounding+=lin + i, col + j
```

Comment: Still got an error of list index out of range line 15, in printMat print('[',matrix[i][j],']',sep = " ",end=' ') IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That's a different issue that arises because `surrounding` returns matrices of a shape that `printMat` doesn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

`surrounding` will return a list (one dimensional object). You store it in `f`, then you call a function on it, which excepts a matrix (in fact list of lists).

So you will not be able to subscript that object twice. That's why you get the error.

If you want to use the same function for output, you could simply pass `[f]` instead of `f` to the printer function.

Comment: Still got an error of list index out of range

line 15, in printMat
    print('[',matrix[i][j],']',sep = " ",end=' ')
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It's because you have fixed the output sizes: 9x9. But your input is not corresponding to that. You need to specify the size based on the input matrix size. `for i in range(len(matrix))` and for the inner loop `for j in range(len(matrix[i]))` for example. That would solve the errors. But I would also consider @ForceBrus answer for saving your surroundings as a list of pairs to have a meaningful format, not just a long flattened list.

Comment: It solved the index out of range error, but now it only return the number of surrounding bombs according to the input. It should return the full grid with the number of surrounding bombs

Comment: I see. Then you should actually create a full 9x9 matrix when you track the surroundings, and place the correct number of bombs in it.